# Parse DB temporary storing query results

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I'm quiet new to JavaScript/TypeScript (nevertheless, I'm doing pretty well with OOP Languages like C#, Java,...) and I'm a bit confused by callback functions especially when it comes to use them with the BaaS ParseDB.

Example: Find all playlists for a certain user requires a query like this one:

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(Playlist);

    query.equalTo("user", user);
    query.find({
        success: function (usersPlaylists: Array<Playlist>)
        {
            alert("Playlists loaded: " + usersPlaylists.length);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, my problem with that is, that the loaded usersPlaylists are just valid within the callback function. I don't see any possibility to store them in some of my own objects.

What I have tried out so far, was to create an object with an array of playlist objects and assign each element from the query result to that objects array. But it didn't work out, because after the callback function finished, the objects array had suddenly 0 elements in it.

The reason for the storage in one of my objects is that, I don't want to query the playlists for each small operation that could be done. E.g. user wants to know, if there is a list with more than 5 elements? I would just have my local list and check it out there, instead of doing again a query.

Thanks in advance,
Tukk

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results by keeping the context of 'this' (and thus having access to other class fields/methods) for example by using arrow functions:

```
class PlayListContainer
{
    private m_localList: Array<Playlist>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.m_localList = [];
    }

    public find()
    {   
        var query = new Parse.Query(Playlist);

        query.equalTo("user", user);

        query.find({
            success: (usersPlaylists: Array<Playlist>) =>
            {
                this.m_localList.concat(usersPlaylists);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was close to the solution I was searching for. Editted it as it worked for me. Thank you very much :)